# Failed Resque Job for Devise Invitable - undefined method `invitation_instructions' for #<User:0x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, resque, devise-invitable, apartment-gem

Ruby on Rails Project, I'm running Resque to process emails (in particular Devise and Devise Invitable). Devise emails are sending fine (out via API through postmark gem) but devise_invitable emails are failing in Resque with `undefined method invitation_instructions for #User:0x0xxxxxx Did you mean? invitations_count`.

When sending through the default devise mailer it all works fine, but fails with my custom mailer. I am wanting to add an inline attachment, hence the need for a custom mailer.

Custom Devise Mailer:

```
class DeviseMailer < Devise::Mailer
    helper  :application

    include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers
    include Devise::Mailers::Helpers
    include DeviseInvitable::Mailer

    default template_path: 'devise/mailer'
    default from: sender@example.com
    layout  'mailer_devise'

    before_action :add_inline_attachment!

    def reset_password_instructions(record, token, opts={})
        super
    end

    def invitation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
        @token = token
        devise_mail(record)#, record.invitation_instructions || :invitation_instructions, opts)
      end

    private

    def add_inline_attachment!
        attachments.inline['logo.png'] = File.read(Rails.root.join('app/assets/images/logo.png'))
    end
end
```

Summary:

`def reset_password_instructions` - working fine

`def invitation_instructions` - failing with undefined method error

Comment: How are you calling the method `invitation_instructions` and from where?

Comment: It gets called from the standard devise invite view (/devise/invitations/new) or I get the same error when running `User.invite!(email: "test@example.com")` from a rails console. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ended up migrating to Sidekiq for other reasons. Below is my updated Devise Mailer Class, which is working well. There was no need to define the `invitation_instructions` method as the `before_action` callback was attaching the inline image, what was what i was after in the beginning.

```
class DeviseMailer < Devise::Mailer
  helper  :application
  include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers
  include Devise::Mailers::Helpers
  include DeviseInvitable::Mailer

  default template_path: 'devise/mailer'
  default from: ENV['EMAIL_NAME']
  layout  'mailer_devise'

  before_action :add_inline_attachment!

  private

  def add_inline_attachment!
    attachments.inline['logo.png'] = File.read(Rails.root.join('app/assets/images/logo.png'))
  end
end
```